# How do I connect my django app to facebook?

Tags: android, python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I connect my django app to facebook if the front-end is an android app. Do I use the android facebook sdk or do I do this server side?

Comment: how is it both an android app and a django app? Do you mean you are accessing a django app through mobile device (android, in this case)?

Comment: It is written in django in the server side so that I can store a user's posts,comments and photos and the API will be accessed by an android client. I have already written the server side and the client code to access the API. Now I need to add facebook graph functionality to it.So to answer your question yes I am accessing it through a native android app.